# Python support missing

Tags: python, vim

I installed vim from source according to this [link](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source) and it was succesful. But there is no `python- support`. I have installed `python-dev` and I've looked for the directory the Python `config-file` is in to set the right flag:

```
--with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python2.7-config
--enable-pythoninterp
```

I've installed vim from source two times, because the first time I forgot sth. 
How can I get `python-support` now?

Comment: Define Python support. When running `vim --version`, you should have `+python` and/or `+python3` in there.

Comment: Since you ran `./configure --enable-pythoninterp`, i am surprised you have `-python` instead of `+python`.

Answer (score 1):

The installation guide you showed also states

> You may need to add `--with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu/` to the configure call.

Have you tried this?

FYI, this is the contents of the directory on my Debian jessie (aka testing) x86_64.

```
$ ls /usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu
Makefile  Setup  Setup.config  Setup.local  config.c  config.c.in
install-sh*  libpython2.7-pic.a  libpython2.7.a  libpython2.7.so@  makesetup*  python.o
```

Comment: I tried this. But it' s not working. After the first installation there was `+python`. Maybe there was a mistake because I installed it a second time?

Comment: and how can I compile the source code again, after changing the configurations?

Comment: The most conservative way would be to rename the old source/build directory(ies) and unzip the source archive again, so that you can compare the new config results with the previous one.